# How to pass variables from a class to an extension of an object that the class is using?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-extensions

I have been on this for awhile now and no matter what I look up I can't seem to understand this. Suppose I'm extending UIView to add a toolbar on keyboard, I am not entirely sure how to pass parameters I need to access from the class that is using that UIView so that I can perform actions upon tapping on the newly created toolbar items in that extension.

Say I have implemented a UITextView in a class:

```
class MyClass : UIViewController { 
var paramToAcess : String!             //param to access in extension 

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    let textView = UITextView() 
textView.addToolBar()                 //using the extension to add toolbar
self.view.addSubview(textView) 
}

//////// other methods /////// 
}
```

and here is the extension:

```
extension UITextView  {

 func addToolBar(){
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.gray

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePressed))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelPressed))
            toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)

        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    func donePressed(){
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func cancelPressed(){
        self.resignFirstResponder()
        //how to access parameters in MyClass to do stuff here? 
    }

}
```

I know that extensions cannot have stored property, I have tried to use a protocol but cannot implement it properly. Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't; not like that. It would break the MVC model to try and access the class from those two functions. If you really need something to happen specific to the class, then you can create the toolbar insider your class. You should only need an extension if you are using this toolbar many times.

Comment: I agree, subclassing seems to be a good choice. But am curious if there are other ways and what would those be .. thanks for comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you cannot have stored properties as part of a class extension you might find it easier to implement this by subclassing:

```
class MyTextViewWithToolbar: UITextView {
    ...
}
```

Then you can include whatever properties you need in the new class.

Basically I think that a class extension is not the best way to implement this requirement, but subclassing will let you do what you have tried above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is definitely an answer, I'm just curious if there are other ways, and if yes, what would those be ... will accept this if nothing better shows up ..

Comment: Well, if there is only ever one instance of your view controller you could make it a singleton and access it from your class extension. I strongly advise you not to do that because it isn't a good design, the subclassing solution is cleaner.

Comment: I agree, not a fan of singleton

Comment: I'm just curious so I leave this till tomorrow see if anyone else has a different approach .. cheers